# shell script about remove words in a file

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to write a shell script to remove words from a file.The words is given in another file. for example:

Input file:

```
I am new in shell script,so I need you help ,thank you
```

Words file:

```
am
in
so
```

and the Output file should be:

```
I  new  shell script, I need you help ,thank you
```

I try to write a script like this:

```
cat words_file | while read line
do
        sed "s/$line//g" input >output
done
```

but only the last word "so" can be removed, how can I save the result in every loop so that I can removed every words ,or is there another way to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would better go and use `awk` for this task:

```
awk 'FNR==NR {words[$1]; next}
     {for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i in a) $i=""}1'
     words input
```

With your files:

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR {words[$1]; next} {for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i in words) $i=""}1' words input
I  new  shell script,so I need you help ,thank you
```

This reads all the words in `words` file and stores them in an array `words[]`. Then, it goes through the lines in `input` and removes those words that appear in the array `words[]`.

Comment: problem solved! thanks a lot . by the way , awk is so amazing.

Comment: I agree!! If you want to go further in `awk` knowledge, I recommend you to go through [Idiomatic awk](http://backreference.org/2010/02/10/idiomatic-awk/). A lot of fun there : )

Answer (score 2):

This should help

```
#!/bin/bash

cat inputfile | while read line
do
        sed -i "s/$line//g" input
done
```

Where inputfile contains the words to remove 
and input is the file you want to remove them from

Comment: I don't see where are you reading the words. I tested and [to me] it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Simply

```
while read word; do
    sed "s/$word//g" input > output    # Output to other file
done < words_file
```

or

```
while read word; do
    sed -i "s/$word//g" input          # In place edit
done < words_file
```

Comment: do not say `for word in ``cat words...``...`. Just say `while read ... do; ... ; done < file`.

Comment: It is not wrong but it can lead to bad behaviour. With the `for $(cat)` you are reading all the file on one shot, whereas a `while... done <file` handles it properly. Also, `sed "" input > output` will break because you will read the same file all the time, so the changes in one shot will disappear on the next one.